# list links to nodes in another node with Views

Tags: 7, views, entities

I'm currently struggling with the following scenario:

There are two different Content Types:

- Offer
- Event

What I want to achieve is this:

There are 6 offers and each of those offers have several events that are nodes as well, in those event nodes there's a field for the date when the event takes place. 
For example: one of the offers is a photography workshop and I want a section in this node where the dates of the events (as a link to the event node) are listed.

<del>I was thinking about creating a taxonomy with all the offers, whenever a event is created you have to select one of the tags.
In a second step I thought Views would be a good way to create this list of all the event dates to a specific offer by showing Content of type Event but I don't know where to go from there because I can't specifiy that it should only show the events with a specific tag.</del>

**EDIT**

Alright I think I'm a bit closer to the solution, but I'd still need some assistance from you guys.

What I did:
Besides [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), I installed [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva).
Created a View that is neither a Page nor a Block with the following settings:

Fields
– Filter Criteria
–– Content: Type (=Event)

Added an Entity Content with the following settings:

Entity content settings
– Entity type: Node
– Bundles: Offer

Not sure where to go from there though. Can I add some kind of `Contextual Filters` or `Relationships` between the Offer and the Events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the offer node holds a reference to the event node, this can easily be done without any custom modules.

- Create a view with content type = offer.
- Create a relationship to the event using 'A bridge to the Content entity that is referenced via', not 'A bridge to the Content entity that is referencing Content via'.
- Add the date field into the field and use the relationship.

So for example, if it's a table view and you have one offer and two events, you should have two rows. offer 1 and event 1 date, and offer 1 and event 2 date. If you want them combined into offer 1 and event 1 date + event 2 date, then you can combine them using views distinct filter.

Comment: That sounds promising, thanks a lot! I'm afraid I'm missing a module here, do I need to get the [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module? Currently I only have the [Entity References](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module installed.

Comment: Entity reference should be enough

Comment: Still playing around with the settings but this worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use node reference field for this scenario [nodereference_field](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodereference_field)

Comment: Thank you for the module suggestions! Though I'd really like to implement that with Views, also since the module isn't covered by Drupal’s security advisory policy…